# Wpf, .resx resource file. Accessing bmp

Tags: wpf

I have a Wpf application project called `WpfTest` which references `WpfTestLib` (A class library).

WpfTestLib has a resources file `MyResources.resx` in a project folder called `Resources`. `MyResources` contains a single bmp, bar.bmp. The resource name is `bar`.

In `MyResources.Designer.cs` I can see

`namespace WpfTestLib.Resources {`

and

`public class MyResources {`

and

`public static System.Drawing.Bitmap bar {`

I've tried to get the image in code by:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(@"/WpfTestLib;component/Resources/MyResources/bar", UriKind.Relative);
```

I've tried various combinations for the `Uri`, but no luck. Any ideas? I can get the bar if I add it as an image to the project, with a type of resource. But in this case I want to access it as part of a resource file.

Thanks

Edit: Actually it's two questions. I have answers to both, but not the bit in the middle that holds it together.

So I can retrieve the image in code using `MyResources.bar`, which returns a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

I can also set the my WPF Image to a resource image using the Uri format shown above. What I can't do is initialize a WPF Image with a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, nor can I find a mapping `Uri` for a .resx. Hope that helps (you to help me :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the issue. There's plenty of information [here](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/04/wpf_binding_to_image_control.html): That gave me the information I needed to deal with an image properly. Using old style resource dictionaries was then easy peasy.